# QTCaptureSession Threading Issue

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, webcam, qtkit

I'm currently working on a project that involves opening and receiving data from a webcam. On OS X we use the QTKit along with QTCaptureSession to access the webcam. The module we are developing is loaded as a plugin by some thread of the main process which causes the following problem:

The addInput method of QTCaptureSession [seems](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-api/2009/Apr/msg00101.html) to wait for some event to processed on the 'main loop'. As the main-loop is never triggered by the main thread (its not a native Cocoa application) the thread invoking the plugin hangs forever.

A similar problem has been described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703754/addinput-method-of-qtcapturesession-not-returning). One suggested solution is to sprinkle the main-thread with calls to `CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, YES);` We tested this and it works, but causes unnecessary (and plugin dependent) code to be added to the main-application.

My question is: is there any way to 'host' the main-event loop QTCaptureSession talks to inside the plugin? For example: Create some artificial thread that is able to trigger the main-loop etc.

Note that we need to get this to work on OS X 10.6.